# Get json datas from C# to javascript without using [WebMethod]

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I have a C# Project, and a ASP.NET project (without database).

I want to call some methods from my C# Project, get the results in JSON and use it in my javascript without using the [WebMethod], I tried to make a Controller but I'm a little bit lost.

If you have any tips it would be nice, thank you.

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use `WebMethod`?

Comment: I want that my C# is runat server and not by the javascript. [WebMethod] deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the controller should look like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [...]
    public virtual ActionResult GetExample()
    {
        [...]
        var result = ...;
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Update(MyModel model)
    {
        [...]
        var result = model
        return Json(result);
    }
    [...]
}
```

And from your java script file you make an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<path>/Home/GetExample",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        [...]
    }
})
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<path>/Home/Update",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $(#my-form).serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        [...]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation so adding my comments here. You probably want to use Web Api here which is the reason you created controller. You probably need to refer Web Api site which will help you build controllers and expose interface to be called from javascript.
[Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)